# AWS CodeBuild: how to access app in localhost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, sonarqube, aws-codebuild

I am trying to run an **AWS CodeBuild** project based on the SonarQube image. 
Via the `buildspec.yaml`, I want to perform some operations using the SonarQube APIs (e.g. generate the token for a user via the `/api/user_tokens/generate` API), but I can't reach the application using `localhost`.
For testing purpose, I am using the CodeBuild agent described on the official documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/use-codebuild-agent.html).
The command I run is:

```
./codebuild_build.sh -i sonarqube:latest -a ./output -b ./buildspec.yaml
```

and this is the `buildspec.yaml`:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    on-failure: ABORT
    run-as: root
    commands:
      - apt update
      - apt install -y net-tools curl 
  post_build:
    commands:
      - netstat -tuln
      - curl http://localhost:9000
```

what I get:

```
...
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/07/26 07:48:16 Phase complete: INSTALL State: SUCCEEDED
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/07/26 07:48:16 Phase context status code:  Message:
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/07/26 07:48:16 Entering phase PRE_BUILD
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/07/26 07:48:16 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/07/26 07:48:16 Phase context status code:  Message:
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/07/26 07:48:16 Entering phase BUILD
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/07/26 07:48:16 Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/07/26 07:48:16 Phase context status code:  Message:
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/07/26 07:48:16 Entering phase POST_BUILD
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/07/26 07:48:16 Running command netstat -tuln
agent_1  | Active Internet connections (only servers)
agent_1  | Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
agent_1  | tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:46439        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
agent_1  | udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:55056        0.0.0.0:*
agent_1  |
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/07/26 07:48:16 Running command curl http://localhost:9000
agent_1  |   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
agent_1  |                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
agent_1  | curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9000 after 0 ms: Connection refused
agent_1  |
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/07/26 07:48:16 Command did not exit successfully curl http://localhost:9000 exit status 7
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/07/26 07:48:16 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: FAILED
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/07/26 07:48:16 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: curl http://localhost:9000. Reason: exit status 7
agent-resources_agent_1 exited with code 0
```

As you can see via the `netstat` command, there is nothing on port 9000 (SonarQube default port), and the address `127.0.0.11` appears instead of the expected `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0`. 
Moreover, I noticed that for every run I get different port numbers.

There is nothing wrong with the SonarQube image in fact if I run a docker container locally with the command:

```
docker run -d --name sonarqube sonarqube:latest
```

and then I run this command:

```
docker exec -it -u 0 sonarqube bash -c "apt update; apt install -y net-tools curl; netstat -tuln; curl http://localhost:9000"
```

I get the expected output with the application listening on port 9000. The `curl`, in fact, shows the html SonarQube page:

```
...
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40501         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9092          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN  <--------
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="application-name" content="SonarQube" />
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF" />
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-512x512.png" />
    <title>SonarQube</title>
...
```

How do I achieve the same goal on CodeBuild? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure if you have not already tried this, but have you added the -p 9000:9000 do your docker command? This has tripped me up so many times, expecting Docker run to automatically enable listening network sockets. So it might be that the process inside the container is listening, but you have not enabled it to communicate with the outside world.

Comment: In your buildspec.yml file, have you tried setting network_mode: "host" ?

Comment: Hi @RicardoSueiras. I omitted on purpose the `-p 9000:9000` to show that even if no port is bound to the local machine, inside the container the application (SonarQube) still works. Reguarding the buildspec.yml, no `network_mode: "host"` seems to be applicable reading the official doc (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html)

Comment: ah you are right, apologies I was getting confused between buildspec and the ecs configuration file I was looking at.

Comment: I think CodeBuild overrides the image's entrypoint to its own executor when it launches the container, so it might be worth trying in the build stage to explicity start sonarcube and see if that works. so as the first post_build: -> commands: -> {start demon} . From the screenshots above, this is kind of what you are seeing as there is nothing listening on port 9000

Comment: I had the same doubt and I already tested it but it gives me something strange: if I add `/opt/sonarqube/docker/entrypoint.sh` (which is the entrypoint according to the official image https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/blob/9b79d014844155923673ca1fbe72ecc0d9ff361c/10/community/Dockerfile) before the `netstat` command, I get the error `Error: Unable to access jarfile lib/sonarqube.jar` and can't move on.

Comment: Moreover, I checked for that file and it DOES exist. It seems like the path in `entrypoint.sh` is wrong since it should be `../lib/sonarqube.jar` and not `lib/sonarqube.jar`

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround. 
CodeBuild seems to override SonarQube entrypoint, so I can manually execute the entrypoint, which is (according to the official [Sonar image](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/blob/9b79d014844155923673ca1fbe72ecc0d9ff361c/10/community/Dockerfile)) the `/opt/sonarqube/docker/entrypoint.sh` file. 
However, this gives me the error `Error: Unable to access jarfile lib/sonarqube.jar`. 
Since the `entrypoint.sh` does a little more than just execute the `lib/sonarqube.sh`, I can manually execute that file without passing through the `entrypoint.sh` file. Be aware that sonarqube can't be executed as `root`. 
After that I wait for SonarQube to be fully initialized and then I can execute other commands on it. 
The final `buildspec` should look like this:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    on-failure: ABORT
    run-as: root
    commands:
      - apt update
      - apt install -y net-tools curl 
  build:
    run-as: sonarqube
    commands:
      - java -jar $SONARQUBE_HOME/lib/sonarqube.jar -Dsonar.log.console=true &
      - while ! curl -s http://localhost:9000 -o /dev/null; do echo "SonarQube is still starting.."; sleep 5; done
  post_build:
    run-as: root
    commands:
      - netstat -tuln
      - curl http://localhost:9000
```

Waiting a more elegant solution, hope it helps someone.